# Reload Youtube page when I play a video?

Tags: javascript, youtube

Hello I want a code to reload the youtube page when I play a video because I have a script that creates a button to download youtube videos but the ids of the videso don't update because youtube don't really reload the page when playing a video.

(java script please)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.reload()` to reload the page

[location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

Comment: No because I try it and don't works with  youtube

Comment: i just checked on chrome console, it worked for me

Comment: @Aitronssesin Are you using iframe? You can get the id by window.location.pathname without need to reload.